# How to change the Shadow darkness in eevee with HDR map?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

My shadow on my scene is so bright, i want change it , is it possible? [image]

Comment: HDR environments don't cast shadows in EEVEE as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

HDRIs are essentially providing fill lighting and there are a few ways you can get a higher contrast shadow.

Very simply, you can set up your HDR material like this to reduce the intensity to your taste. This will work with whatever HDR you choose.

[image]

In a bigger sense you want to make sure that the HDR you choose emulates the lighting conditions you want in your scene.

If you choose that was taken at 9:00 AM on a rainy day in Northern England, there's no way you're going to achieve the effect of a desert scene at high noon, or a darkened, gloomy warehouse.

When the sun is very bright and clear, and there isn't alot of reflective material around the shadow will be very sharp and dark, when there are alot of clouds the sunlight gets bounced around alot more and the shadow gets filled with photons, therefore looking much more diffuse and lighter.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a **sun lamp aligned with HDR** main light source, then I **lower the HDR light power**. The result is quite different from that obtained with Cycles, but somehow it is satisfying, at least for me.